# d3S Force Layout: Custom made node components

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just had an idea with d3s consisting of two steps:

1. Make this nice clock interactive, thus allowing the user to specify a date graphically. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355
2. Adding several of these as nodes to a force graph http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/929623

For 1. I'd like to have the user click and drag on the time arcs to modify their position, so they indicate the date the user wants to specify. What would be the easiest and most straight forward way to achieve this?

For 2. How could I scale my interactive clocks down and append them as node elements?

Thanks for your help!

Update:

So I managed to react on drag events and calculate a diff with Math.tan().

Now I'm stuck on modifying the arc itself.

```
    var width = 961,
    height = 800,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 5,
    spacing = .10;

var formatSecond = d3.time.format("%S s"),
    formatMinute = d3.time.format("%M m"),
    formatHour = d3.time.format("%H h"),
    formatDay = d3.time.format("%a"),
    formatDate = d3.time.format("%d d"),
    formatMonth = d3.time.format("%b");

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["hsl(-180,50%,50%)", "hsl(180,50%,50%)"])
    .interpolate(interpolateHsl);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.value * 2 * Math.PI; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return d.index * radius; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return (d.index + spacing) * radius; })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var field = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(fields)
    .enter().append("g");

var dragTransformation = [];
var dragOrig = [];
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", function() {
            dragTransformation = [0, 0];
            dragOrig = d3.mouse(this);
        })
        .on("drag", function(d,i) {
              thisArc = d3.select(this);
              dragTransformation[0] += d3.event.dx;
              dragTransformation[1] += d3.event.dy;
        })
        .on("dragend", function() {
            var xDiff = dragTransformation[0] / dragOrig[0];
            var yDiff = dragTransformation[1] / dragOrig[1];
            var diffFactor = Math.tan(xDiff / yDiff);
            /**
             * -----------------------------------------------------------------------
             * Change arc start + end angle here
             *
             */
             d3.select(this).
                attr("value", function(d) { console.log("HERE", d); return 3; });
        });

field.append("path");
field.append("text");

// Calls drag on arc element
field.call(drag);

tick();
//d3.transition().duration(0).each(tick);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

function arcTween(d) {
  var i = d3.interpolateNumber(d.previousValue, d.value);
  return function(t) { d.value = i(t); return arc(d); };
}

function tick() {
  field = field
      .each(function(d) { this._value = d.value; })
      .data(fields)
      .each(function(d) { d.previousValue = this._value; });

  field.select("path")
    .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attrTween("d", arcTween)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

  field.select("text")
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.value < .5 ? "-.5em" : "1em"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
      .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .attr("class", "white")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + 360 * d.value + ")"
            + "translate(0," + -(d.index + spacing / 50) * radius + ")"
            + "rotate(" + (d.value < .5 ? -90 : 90) + ")"
            + "rotate(90)"
      });

  //setTimeout(tick, 1000 - Date.now() % 1000);
}

function fields() {
  var now = new Date;
  return [{
        index: .7,
        text: formatSecond(now),
        value: now.getSeconds() / 60
    },{
        index: .6,
        text: formatMinute(now),
        value: now.getMinutes() / 60
    },{
        index: .5,
        text: formatHour(now),
        value: now.getHours() / 25
    },{
        index: .3,
        text: formatDay(now),
        value: now.getDay() / 7
    },{
        index: .2,
        text: formatDate(now),
        value: (now.getDate() - 1) / (32 - new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), 32).getDate())
    },{
        index: .1,
        text: formatMonth(now),
        value: now.getMonth() / 12
    }
  ];
}

// Avoid shortest-path interpolation.
function interpolateHsl(a, b) {
  var i = d3.interpolateString(a, b);
  return function(t) {
    return d3.hsl(i(t));
  };
}
```

The arcs were drawn with data generated from the current date (fields function) which is updated on every tick.

How would I change the arc's start and endAngle with the value i've generated with the oneMouseDown function and map it to the date data (thus actually setting a new date when modifying the arc)? I've found approaches with

```
d3.select(this)...attr()...
```

but didn't find way to access ther start or endAngle attribute.

Comment: For 1 you'd have to use `Math.tan (y/x)` to get the angle and then you could interpolate that into the value. As for 2, all you have to do is make each node a `g` element and append all the objects for the clock into that element. To scale, you should be able to simply change the radius variable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I'm going to try out that approach soon and then let you know how it went.

Comment: Hey, I've tried the Math.tan approach but am still having trouble modifying the arc start and end angle (see above). Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass the arc generator a JSON object with the fields specified `{startAngle: x, endAngle: y};`, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/boblanders/ztqjr9xr/6/).

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your help!